# Wondering why this only deletes node #2

Tags: c++

Currently, this program will only delete node #1 (from the first if statement) and node #2, but none past that. Wondering what do I do wrong?

```
void removeMovie(myMovies *& firstMoviePtr, int removeNode)
{

    int index = 1;

    myMovies *temp;

    myMovies *prev;

    myMovies *nextNode=0;

    if (removeNode==1) {
        firstMoviePtr = firstMoviePtr->next;
    }
    else {
        for (prev = firstMoviePtr; prev; prev = prev->next)

        {

            if (index == removeNode )
            {
                nextNode = prev->next;
                break;
            }
            else { index++; }

        }
        for (myMovies * nodePtr = firstMoviePtr; nodePtr; nodePtr = nodePtr->next)
        {

            if (nodePtr->next == prev)nodePtr->next = nextNode; break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `if (nodePtr->next == prev)nodePtr->next = nextNode; break;` this is not Python: `break` is outside of the `if` here. Also, please scope your variables correctly.

Comment: @Quentin Answers go in the answer section; this is not Twitter

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Typos are not considered useful questions.

Comment: @Quentin: Doesn't matter. If you feel it's not useful enough to answer then you don't have to. But, if you do, it should be done in the proper place. Comments cannot be peer reviewed. That's the fundamental basis of SO: it's a ranked Q&A, not a forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
if (nodePtr->next == prev)nodePtr->next = nextNode; break;
```

This can be rewritten with some formatting like this:

```
if (nodePtr->next == prev)
   nodePtr->next = nextNode;

break;
```

The point being that your loop will *always* break. On the first iteration. You won't get a second one.

---

If you want to make both statements conditional, use braces (`{}`), like this:

```
if (nodePtr->next == prev)
{
   nodePtr->next = nextNode;
   break;
}
```

*(Disclaimer: I haven't checked whether this logic is actually correct for the algorithm you're trying to implement.)*

Or, on one line:

```
if (nodePtr->next == prev) { nodePtr->next = nextNode; break; }
```

(But please don't.)

Comment: Just went though and tested it after making that correction. Everything works now and the logic is correct.